# Twiiter PHP API Application access Direct Messages Permission?

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth

I have set my application permissions as "read, Write, Direct Messages" as shown in the figure
[image]

I have saved these settings.

But when i authenticate my app. it shows that my application will not be able to access direct messages.As shown in the figure
[image]

Please help me, i am stuck with this problem from many days.
 I am using abraham oauthtwitter api 
from here https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth

Comment: How were you able to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call **Authorize Url**. This issue can apear if you call "Authenticate Url".

Answer (score 1):

if you have changed your settings you'll need to regenerate the keys

Comment: I have regenrated the keys, But the issue is still there.

Comment: recheck all your settings, Twitter has a habit of defaulting back to read-only access.

Comment: still same issue. One intresting thing is that in my accesstoken which i genereate from settings page shows access level  Read, write, and direct messages

Comment: is it just twitter at fault, does your app still work? can you get your DMs ?!!

Comment: No i cant get DM. it says. your application does not have access to DM

Comment: hmm. i would perhaps try deleting and restarting your twitter app form again.  i had to complete this twice, before i could get my app to work. - sorry i can't be of more help

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6421/discussion-between-asghar-and-4t4)