# Access direct messages via Twitter API

Tags: php, oauth, twitter

I am trying to access the Twitter direct messaging API.

I have set up an app and set the permissions to `Read, write, and direct messages`:

[image]

However, when I test the application and see the authorisation screen, direct messaging is not included in the permission list:

[image]

I have tried creating fresh applications, resetting the keys once the permission have been changed and only creating the access tokens once the permissions have been updated. However, I still cannot get the `Read, write, and direct messages` permissions to kick in.

I am using HybridAuth as a framework to acccess the Twitter API.

I note [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8725974/twiiter-php-api-application-access-direct-messages-permission) question, however no answer has been provided as the solution may have been established in a chat session which is longer available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

edit

```
hybridauth\Hybrid\Providers\Twitter.php
```

find

```
$this->api->authorize_url = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate";
```

replace by

```
$this->api->authorize_url = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize";
```

cf: https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/1253